# Clone an element without the children in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and I want to clone it without its children. Note that I simplified the markup for brevity, the table has many properties and event handlers which I also want to copy.

```
<table data-x="..." class="a b c">
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    .
    .
    .
</table>
```

I don't want to copy all then delete the children afterwards, I'm not sure but I think it's not efficient.

Comment: Then why don't you just create `table` using jquery

Comment: I don't think `jQuery` has that but you can do that with plain JavaScript. `node.cloneNode()`. This won't copy attached event listeners - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

Comment: @Tushar see edited post. I just made the markup simple.

Comment: Please post the complete HTML in jsBin or PasteBin and specify which all are you planning to retain in the cloned copy

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu I think you should post that as an answer, of all the response, yours is a real answer...

Comment: @dpp I think you don't know how to do what you want to do and, at same time, looks like if you know it with clarity. Cloning an element it's possible and, if you have delegate event handlers assigned to the element, they will work as expected. You can vote negative all answers if you want, thinking that cloning an element then modify is not efficient, so... Hope you achieve it 

Comment: Wow! All other guys only know how to complain, not to cooperate and provide a solution. I made the post clear and they downvoted the post to death and even want it to be closed? Whatever happened to SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can clone just the element without it's children using `jQuery` but you can do that with plain JavaScript. `node.cloneNode()`. This won't copy attached event listeners

[cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)

Comment: I'll start with this solution. Now I just need to copy all event handlers which I know how to do.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use [cloneNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)

```
var $table = $('table');
var clone = $table[0].cloneNode(); //without deep property
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tkLakm7e/)

Note: Any jQuery listeners and data associated won't be copied

Answer (score -1):

You can do it easily with jQuery `.clone()`:

```
var $new_table = $('table').clone();
$newtable.html(''); // which returns <table></table>
```

Comment: It's the workaround to clone an element. First clone, then modify. Else you can just do `var $new_table = $('<table/>');`.

Comment: look, I knew that already, I'm looking for a more efficient way.

Comment: This is the way. Using delegate events you can achieve it easily. I don't know easiest (and better) ways to clone an element (using jQuery).

Comment: Isn't clear enough? That's what I'm already doing, now I'm looking for a more efficient way, I have many tables and each table has so many rows and copying them and removing them afterwards is not an option.

Comment: Then transform it a little to use native `.cloneNode()`: `var $new_table = $('table')[0].cloneNode()`

Answer (score -1):

If i think then you can create a new table itself using jquery. Since you did not provide the code that you are using i am giving you an example.

```
<div id='tabdiv'>
</div>
```

simple jquery code:

```
$('#tabdiv').html('<table></table');
```

This will create a new empty table in the div with this new table

Answer (score -1):

Try this: You can Remove the childrens if you dont need them.

```
var newtable = $('table').clone();
newtable.find('tr').remove(); // or you can remove anything you want  to remove from it
```

Now in new table you will have table without any rows.
Hope this works.

Comment: I'm looking for a more efficient way that's why I don't prefer copy-delete solution. I have many tables with many rows, I just can't use this solution anymore.